# How create a MonthPicker in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, datepicker, uipickerview, swiftui

I would like display a date picker contained only month and year.

The default `DatePicker` display day, month and year. It's not possible to remove day and set a min and max date.

How generate this month picker in SwiftUI?

[image]

Comment: i think you have to do it "manually" ...

Comment: Ok, have you an example for a custom DatePicker in SwiftUI ?

Comment: Do o you just want month names or month and year?

Comment: I would liké Month and year (if possible month and year separated)

Comment: Example here https://github.com/Jinxiansen/SwiftUI/blob/master/README.md#Picker.  Just add a second picker.

Comment: Internally they use `UIDatePicker` (don't ask... couple of crashes) and all modes it has are : .time, .date, .dateAndTime,  and .countDownTimer. So...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the appearance of the DatePicker in the SwiftUI framework to only months and years?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62271628/how-do-i-change-the-appearance-of-the-datepicker-in-the-swiftui-framework-to-onl)